# Showing that $(2)$ is the only maximal ideal of $A.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $A = \{\frac{a}{b} : a,b \in \mathbb Z, b \neq 0, b \text{ is odd }\}.$ Show that $(2)$ is the only maximal ideal of $A.$

Could anyone give me a hint on how to show this please? I am noticing that the denominator in $A$ is always odd, but why so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ideals of the ring of rational numbers with odd denominators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669305/ideals-of-the-ring-of-rational-numbers-with-odd-denominators) Or this one? [Maximal Ideals in the Ring of Rationals whose denominators are not divisible by a prime $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111517/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-rationals-whose-denominators-are-not-divisible-by)

Comment: @ViktorVaughn personally I did not get the idea from this 2 links still there are many details missed

Answer (score 2):

A common strategy: it suffices to show that everything NOT in $(2)$ is a multiplicative unit (because units cannot be contained in any maximal ideals). But this is easy because if $a/b \not\in (2)$, then $a$ is odd, so $b/a$ is a multiplicative inverse for $a/b$ in $A$.

Comment: Why if $a$ is odd, then $b/a$ is a multiplicative inverse?  how this help us in the proof?

Comment: Can you please give a detailed proof? I feel like your idea is simple.

Answer (score 1):

For this question, it is straightforward to characterize all of the ideals of $A$.

Here is a hint.

A nonzero rational number $\mathbb{Q}$ in simplest form has the form $\pm p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_n^{a_n} $ where $p_1, p_2, \cdots p_n$ are prime numbers and each $a_i$ is a nonzero integer. Note that $1$ in this case is the empty product. For example $-\frac{20}{3}$ is $-2^2 \cdot 3^{-1} \cdot 5^1$.

If you have a set of rational numbers $\{ q_1, q_2, \cdots \}$ what ideal do they generate?

---

Let's call our ring $R$.

Let's consider the ideal generated by a single rational number $q$ of the form $\pm 2^{a_1}p_i^{a_i}$ note that $a_1$ must be non-negative.

I claim that $(\pm 2^{a_1}p_i^{a_i})$ is $2^{a_1}R$. Every odd prime number $p$ is a unit because $p^{-1}$ is present in the ideal, so we can multiply by units to get $2^{a_1}$. We also note that $1$ and $2$ are present but $\frac{1}{2}$ is not, so $a_1$ must be non-negative and we can't multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ to recover number with smaller powers of two in their prime factorization.

Next let's move on to the general case $(q_1, q_2, \cdots)$. All numbers can be expressed as $(2^{a_1}x_1, 2^{a_2}x_2, \cdots)$ where $2^{a_i}$ is the largest power of two that can be extracted from $q_i$. I claim that $2^nR$, where $n$ is the smallest value of $a_i$ among all the $i$ in the index set, is generated by $(q_1, q_2, \cdots)$. We can recover all the original generators by multiplying by an element of $R$, i.e. every generator $q_i$ is equal to $2^{a_i}y_i$ for some $y_i$, so they are contained within the ideal. Additionally, we can't get anything outside of $2^nR$ because that would require a multiplicative inverse of $2$.

Comment: I still did not get your idea and I do not know the connections between your primes and my a and b. Also I do not know how to answer your last question .... could you please explain more details?

Comment: All the ideals have the form $2^nR$ where $R$ is the ring. This is because all of the odd primes are units in this ring.

Comment: but $a$ in the above definition is allowed to be anything other than $2$ why you are always assuming that it is $2$?

Comment: What happen when $a=3, 5, 7, ...$ any odd number?

Comment: @MathIgnorance ... I'm factorizing a rational number as a product of prime numbers. Any rational number is a finite product of the form $\pm \prod p_i^{a_i}$ where $a_i$  is $a_i$ nonzero integer. If I insist that all $a_i$ are positive, I get back the integers. This is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations) and the fact that we can represent rational numbers in simplest form.

Comment: I do not understand this idea "A nonzero rational number $\mathbb{Q}$ in simplest form has the form $\pm p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_n^{a_n} $" ..... can you explain it please?

Comment: I can not understand the meaning of the number with smaller powers of $2$ in the statement "to recover number with smaller powers of two in their prime factorization." smaller relative to what?

Comment: @MathIgnorance I added an example of a prime decomposition of a rational number and explained what I meant by recovering the generators.